# send/recv ethernet frame on windows using C++

Tags: c++, networking, driver, ethernet, winpcap

is there any windows library / kernel-mode driver (with usermode API) in C/C++ which I can use to send/recv ethernet frame without IP (only use mac address).

I heard about winpcap, is there any lighter library or wrapper to winpcap which has simple open(), close(), send(), recv() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On unix there is hping http://www.hping.org/ and mausezahn http://www.perihel.at/sec/mz/ but I don't know if any of those compiles under windows. All applications/libraries I know are based on libpcap/winpcap.